# How do I drag and drop a csv source file onto a Dygraph canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, dygraphs

Can I use Filereader in HTML5 to drag and drop a CSV data file onto a Dygraph canvas?  Right now I'm hard-coding the file name (or JS variable containing the file name) into the 'new Dygraph()' assignment.

Comment: This is a cool idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure! The main difference is that FileReader reads a file on the client's machine. The JS variable you pass to the dygraphs constructor is a file name on the server.

Instead of a file name, you can pass CSV data to the dygraphs constructor. Your should use FileReader to read the CSV data out of the file your user drags and drops. Then construct a Dygraph object using that data.